# git push in gnome-term crashes my window manager

Tags: git, openssh

In terminal in awesome wm when i `git push`
awesome wm freezes. so i move over to tty2 and log in. `top` shows awesome at %100 cpu. `ps aux | grep [g]it`
output

```
git-remote-https origin https://github.com/user/user.git.io
/usr/lib/ssh/x11-ssh-askpass Username for "https://github.com"
```

if i git push in linux termnina (no x)

```
Error: can't open display
error: unable to read askpass response from '/usr/lib/ssh/x11-ssh-askpass'
username for "https://github.com":
```

i input username then it give me the errors again and prompts for password then it pushes everything fine.

is there a way to not use the graphical dialog x11-askpath?

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_Keys#x11-ssh-askpass
"The x11-ssh-askpass package provides a graphical dialog for entering your passhrase when running an X session."

damn, i dont want to use this!

Comment: Sounds like git is trying to use a GUI for some reason, or maybe ssh itself is trying to use a GUI to ask for a password. What's the output of `which git`, `git --version`, and `which ssh`?

Comment: git version is 1.9.0, /usr/bin/git, /usr/bin/ssh

Comment: Please paste the entire output of `git --version`...

Comment: Also, what happens when you try to `ssh` somewhere? Do you get the same behavior? git may be invoking ssh in an odd way.

Comment: git version 1.9.0

Comment: i ssh on my local network all the time. no problem but i have keys setup so i dont get prompted anymore.

Comment: ah. Haha. I get more output than that. Ok. Try running `unset SSH_ASKPASS` before running `git push` in the same shell. Does this help?

Comment: i just tired that i set SSH_ASKPATH=''  <-- empty string, same behavior

Comment: Try a full `unset`.

Comment: nope still froze

Comment: @user1855481 how about `SSH_ASKPASS=/bin/false` ?

Comment: ding ding DING!!! we have a winner!! janos come on down!!! that did it bro. should i set that in my bash_profile or .bashrc?